# How to solve for $g(x)$ in $f(x)=\int_a^b g(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$f(x)=\int_a^b g(x) dx$$

Do you just take the derivative and evaluate $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$? Sorry if it seems obvious, but I have never done this before.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a constant which is value nothing but the value the integration of the fixed function $g$ from $a$ to $b$. it is not a function. Given such constant number such a $g$ is not unique.

Comment: Another way of saying what @GA316 said: There is no "unbound" variable $x$ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{If}\;\;F(x) = \underbrace{\int g(x) \,dx}_{\text{indefinite integral}}\;\text{ then }\;\underbrace{f = \int_a^b g(x) \,dx = F(a) - F(b)}_{\text{evaluation of definite integral}},$$ so $f$ as defined will be a constant $C$, and not a function of $x$. As a result, taking the derivative of $f = C$ would then be $(C)' = 0$.

You can not recover $g(x)$ when given only the evaluation of its integral between the bounds $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I sort of understand...Would it be the same if the bounds were from a to x ?

Comment: No, then $f(x)$ would be a function of $x$, so you'd be able to employ the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Essentially, you'd be able to recover $g(x)$ by taking the derivative of $f(x)$. Period. Knowing $a$ would be unnecessary because it would evaluate as a constant, and we'd lose any information provided by it when finding $f'(x) = g(x)$. We'd have that $$g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x g(x)\,dx$$

Comment: See [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus - First Part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) Note, there is some fine print. We need for your $g(x)$ to be continuous on some interval $[a, b]$ and defined for all $x \in (a, b)$...But the idea here is a fundamental one in calculus.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!